# Elaborate creature vocalization and efforts....Who mixes them? DX or FX side?

Tags: sound-design, mixing

I am wondering how sound designers like their creature vocal efforts and vocalizations treated on the dub stage.  To include them with dialogue seems easier as the mixer can process them and set them in an easy smooth level to preceding dialogue but.....they must be set discreet for international fully filled M&E mixes too. Do you prefer the FX mixer or DX mixer mix your creature vocal efforts and non-english vocalizations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tough call.  I can say that on Fright Night 2 I cut them all cut in Design FX (Vamp Vox tracks) and they got routed to the FX stem on the stage.  For which I gathered, as you hit the nail on the head, ensuring it was in the M&E.

Than again, there wasn't much overlap between true dialogue and the vocalizations (as in, minimal hybridization). And no real DX 'treatment's were desired per the director.  it was mostly just Vampire mode or not.  So in this particular case, it made sense to route to FX.  Although if they are serving more integrally to DX, maybe they should go there.

So it seems to come down to that dreaded "it depends" answer.